# Playa Filters failing with Force SSL module in place

Tags: playa, ssl

We are experiencing the same issue as:
https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/https_and_playa_in_cp

We're wanting to use the playa module along with force-ssl(http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dm-force-ssl). Due to various constraints we were unable to apply SSL without this module.

The force-ssl module controls the "URL to your "themes" folder" among other variables. So despite setting it to /themes/ the playa plugin 'filter' feature still does not work.

We experienced the same issue with channel videos. After talking to them they were able to issue a patch that resolved this issue. We're wondering if you could also facilitate integration of the playa and force-ssl module?

I've also tried this and had the same result without force-ssl and just a simple rewrite for the control panel only:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond $1 ^(admin.php) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Taylor

Comment: Sounds like this is a safecracker form? Where are Playa assets loading from?

Comment: Hi siebird, playa is installed normally in expression engine in third party module and third party themes. 

The control panel is subsequently forced HTTPS via either the force-ssl module and I also recently got working with just a simple URL rewrite as shown above.

Comment: What errors does the console show? Are the Playa assets loading from `/themes/third_party/playa/...` or `https://domain.com/themes/third_party/playa/...` ?

Comment: The Links look like.... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/third_party/playa/styles/field.css" />`
And.... 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/third_party/playa/styles/droppanes.css" />`

Comment: The problem persists if using absolut URLs as well:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://domain.com/themes/third_party/playa/styles/field.css" />`

Comment: What version of Playa? Also, how do you know Playa is the culprit?

Comment: playa is at version 4.3.3. 

It is playa functionality that is incomplete. Everything else is fine. Perhaps I didn't make this clear by just refering to the other post. The playa filter/serach function isn't working. All the playa fields appear, they can be selected, but if you type into the filter field, the area grays out, but returns no results. 

We saw a similar issue with Channel Videos where you could start and upload, but it wouldn't complete due to the Control Panel being under HTTPS, but not themes nor the rest of the site.

Comment: Is the Playa field configured to the correct channel? If so, does that channel have entries?

Comment: I believe everything is configured correctly. It works fine with SSL turned off. 

Playa in one channel post: http://i47.tinypic.com/b5offc.png

Playa with filter search graying out and not returning result: http://i48.tinypic.com/x4onqw.png

Comment: Obviously been a long thread would this be better to file a support ticket on? 

Through testing. I've discovered that by making the "URL to the root directory of your site" varrible HTTPS playa starts working again. However, we don't want to set this as we want the main site to be http. Summation. Playa works with https off. Turning https on via force-ssl or modrewrites for admin.php breaks playa.

Comment: Gray, if you look in your dev console, are you seeing any JS errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it’s just the search/filters that aren’t working, Playa uses Ajax to apply those things, which goes through your Site URL, not your themes folder.

If you don’t want to set your main site URL to use SSL, you can give Playa an alternate URL to use by opening up system/expressionengine/config/config.php and adding this:

```
$config['playa_site_index'] = "https://example.com/index.php";
```